# If $\max\limits_{[a,b]}\mid x(t)-y(t)\mid$ bounded then $\sqrt{\int_a^b(x(t)-y(t))^2\text dt}$ bounded?

Tags: calculus, functions, metric-spaces

> Prove or disprove with counter-example: if the set of the functions are bounded at $d(x,y)=\max\limits_{[a,b]}\mid x(t)-y(t)\mid$ then the set also bounded at $d(x,y)=\sqrt{\int_a^b(x(t)-y(t))^2\text dt}$

I think that's correct because if  $\max\limits_{[a,b]}\mid x(t)-y(t)\mid<\infty$ then $\int_a^b(x(t)-y(t))^2\text dt$  must be converge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using real-valued functions.  Put $M=\max\limits_{[a,b]}|x(t)-y(t)|$.  By hypothesis, $M<\infty$.  Then we have
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\int_a^b(x(t)-y(t))^2\ dt}\leq M\sqrt{\int_a^b1\ dt}=M\sqrt{b-a}<\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: By definition, $M\geq0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right